# Do something to two objects and test results for equality

Tags: python

I want to evaluate inline the equality of two objects after an operation is performed on each of them.

How do I test `f(x) == f(y)` without defining a function `f` or replicating the code for `f`?

With `x + 5 == y + 5`, can I write `+ 5` only once, without defining `plus5(a)`?

Comment: I think my question is fine -- can the downvoter clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the results are hashable, you could do

```
len({a+5 for a in [x, y]}) == 1
```

Generally, though, if the operation is sufficiently verbose or error-prone to type that you'd want to avoid repeating it, you might as well make it a named function.